# Get current ChainId in smartPy contract

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy

I'm trying to get the [chain_id](https://smartpy.io/dev/reference.html#_chain_id) of the current chain evaluating a transaction or containing the smart contract with **smartPy**, but I got always error in init and in entrypoints when I try to affect the chainId to a ver in storage, can you anyone give us a small example on how to get the chain_id in the smart contract? or how to initiate a var in storage with the chain_id where the contract is deployed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at https://smartpy.io/dev/reference.html#_chain_id, you can see that you can basically currently do three things in SmartPy:

1. Define chain_id constants with things like `sp.chain_id_cst("0x9caecab9")`.
2. Get the current chain_id for your chain `sp.chain_id`.
3. Verify that they match with `sp.verify_equal`.

There are no helper lists of chain_id constants that I know of, which would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for answering, I saw the docs and tried to apply in samrt contract but my problem is that I got errors when I want to get the current chain_id, for example when I want to initiante a var in storage with sp.chai_id I got, 

Error: Error in Scenario 
Missing environment 
(sp.chain_id : sp.TChainId) 
Compute storage 
Traceback (most recent call last): 

So if you can give us an example on how to use it.

Comment: In the storage, you put constants so you need to use `sp.chain_id_cst`.